# jQuery UI dragndrop into iframe gives wrong offset

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

[image]

I have a problem when trying to drag element into iframe, it select another element. Anybody knows why ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this problem using this js

https://gist.github.com/Craga89/8219459